# Why am I getting UT005023: Exception handling request to ... : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ...Lorg/apache/wicket/Application;

Tags: java-10, wicket-7, wildfly-12

I am upgrading a project from Java 8, WildFly 8, Wicket 6 to Java 10, WildFly 12, Wicket 7.10.  The issue is that when I request a page, I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError exception any time my WebApp which extends WebApplication which extends Application calls a method defined in Application.

For example:

```
getRequestCycleSettings()
getMarkupSettings()
getJavaScriptLibrarySettings()
```

etc...

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share at least the stack trace?